# Codeigniter cannot find controller

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using Codeigniter 3. When running on local wamp server, all is good. But, when running on my VPS (Linux Debian Apache 2.2.22) I get a 'URL not found' message.

here is the controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Contact extends CI_Controller {
      public function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function index()
    {
      $this->load->view('contact_view');
    }
  }
```

My URL to this controller is www.example.com/Contact

Error message is:

> The requested URL /index.php/Contact was not found on this server.

I have removed index.php from `$config['index_page'] = ''`

In my .htaccess file, I am using rewrite to eleminite the need for index.php in URLs, using this:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

The directives on my virtual host are:
`<Directory "/var/www/example">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>`

mod_rewrite is definitely enabled on virtual host.

Everything works fine on my local machine, running Wampserver, but why does it not work on my VPS?

Comment: If you put random characters at the top of your htaccess file, do you get a 500 error?

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] - try with this... (question mark after index.php) - it helped me on some servers/hosts... Even here some posters mentioned it... http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-1236.html

Comment: Yes - on both servers

Comment: @nevermind Question mark solved it, thanks. Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Codeigniter 3, I had to Capitalize the first letter of the Controller filename. So for example, I changed main.php to be Main.php and that fixed it for me.

Note that I did not have to do that on my localhost windows laptop, but I had to do that on the hostgator unix server.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Question mark after index.php is solution... However, i would like some explanation, too. I know from experience that some servers requires it, but don't know the exact reason.

Comment: I just added the same solution to a different server, which developed the same fault on older sites. All is good there now too. Something must have changed with a server update on that one.

Comment: Try to add `Options -Multiviews` before your rewrite rules. Obviously the rewrite rules are working but if the Multviews option is On on your VPS, you will run into all sorts of issues